# creating email accounts for cpanel using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cpanel

Does anybody know how i can go about creating email accounts and maybe read mails from my cpanel using a rails app without going directly to the cpanel to create the email accounts. This is really help and it can save me a lot a time logging into the cpanel. Which means i should be able to create the email accounts with my rails app. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cPanel have an API that you may access to do the work for you

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/

All you have to do is to build the requests and call their API.

In order to build a request:

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/index.html')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Here is the link for the XML or JSON versions of the API:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/XmlApi

Then you parse the JSON after you request and show in your rails application.

Just for you to know, the function to create e-mails are in API1:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/SoftwareDevelopmentKit/CallingAPIFunctions

I hope this helps you to get started.

Comment: To authenticate I nEed to ender the authentacation credentials for the cpanel. Any ideas were I can put the username and password when building the request